# facebook deep linking android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-intent

I am having trouble deep linking my app to facebook.

I have a facebook app link https://fb.me/744XXXXXXXXXXX

The url with custom scheme is

> "appName://share"

package name is

> com.appName.app

The intent filter for activity which is supposed to receive this intent is

```
<intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="appName"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
```

But I don't know how to prepare the intent which will take the information about the shared item to facebook.

The sample app for facebook deep linking which i downloaded from [here](https://codeload.github.com/AppLinks/Samples/zip/master) provides the link like this

```
http://primenumber.parseapp.com/number?id=7
```

and the intent filter looks like this

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="primenumber-sample-app"/>
<intent-filter/>
```

All i have to do is share the link mentioned above and when I click the shared link in Facebook app the sample app is opened. 
How do I prepare the link as given in the sample app?

And if I have to create a chooser intent which can share data using other apps too, what should the outgoing intent look like? 
I have read and tried to understand the facebook sdk docs but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: I want to share without using the dialogue provided by facebook.

Comment: Have you read the documentation about AppLinks in the Facebook site: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks? This will give you a good overview of how AppLinks works and what you have to do to implement them on Android.
And about sharing, it is recommended to use the Facebook SDK for it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clarified, you are trying to use App Links by facebook in your android app using facebook SDK, so that any link/ graph hosted by your registered facebook page/ app opens up your android application activity and handles the URL based on the path specified by parsing.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this); 
    ...
    Uri targetUrl =
      AppLinks.getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent(this, getIntent());
    if (targetUrl != null) {
        Log.i("Activity", "App Link Target URL: " + targetUrl.toString());
    }
}
```

Also Deep linking is what only Google called its new marshmallow feature using hosted `'./well-known/'` bondage between app and website.